# Foundation 5 top-bar menu (with icons) breaks in two lines

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-5

I am using Foundation 5 (latest, as of time of writing: v5.5.3)

I have set up top-bar menu with some icons for each element.
Basically: top-bar menu works fine unless page width 
is more than [640px] and less than [828px]!

I created a screenshot to better illustrate the problem:
[screenshot of broken top-bar menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq6uK.png)

I prepared a Fiddle illustrating my problem.
(https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/146/)

**Top-Bar HTML:**

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="'Back'">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">My super homepage</a></h1>
            </li>
            <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <!-- Left Nav Section -->
            <ul class="left">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="link-item-exclusive" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-star menu-item"></span>&nbsp; Exclusive goods</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="link-item-new" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-download menu-item"></span>&nbsp; New arrivals</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                <a class="link-item-about" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-warning menu-item"></span>&nbsp; About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Nav Section -->
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a class="link-item-flag" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-flag menu-item"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Choose language</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Language 1</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Language 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Language 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Additional CSS to position icons**

```
span.menu-item
{
    font-size:1.25rem;
    font-weight:500;
    line-height:1.25rem;
}

a.link-item-new span.menu-item,
a.link-item-exclusive span.menu-item
{
    position:relative;
    top:0.1rem;
}

a.link-item-about span.menu-item
{
    position:relative;
    top:0.15rem;
}

a.link-item-flag span.menu-item
{
    position:relative;
    top:0.2rem;
}
```

What CSS rules I need to apply to remove this breakage?
It would be fine if menu just showed up as hamburger 
icon instead of braking up.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please let me know if it's okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a slight modification to your html in that I've added a `span` around the "Choose language" text with a class of `.lang-text` so I can manipulate the content using `@media` queries.

The idea is that when the viewport size reaches the breaking point, only the "Choose language" text is hidden, retaining the flag icon (and the dropdown options with it).

**Html:**

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="'Back'">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">My super homepage</a></h1>
      </li>
      <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <!-- Left Nav Section -->
      <ul class="left">
        <li class="active">
          <a class="link-item-exclusive" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-star menu-item"></span>&nbsp; Exclusive goods</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a class="link-item-new" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-download menu-item"></span>&nbsp; New arrivals</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a class="link-item-about" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-warning menu-item"></span>&nbsp; About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a class="link-item-flag" href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-flag menu-item"></span><span class="lang-text">&nbsp;&nbsp; Choose language</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Language 1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Language 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Language 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**@media queries:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  a.link-item-flag span.lang-text {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 46.5em) {
  a.link-item-flag span.lang-text {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/157/)**

Comment: -- Well, hiding language changer (showing it only for large screens) does not provide good user experience. Sadly, i can not accept this answer to problem at hand.
-- I might try to make some media queries though. Thanks.

Comment: @Rikijs I've updated my answer with what I hope is a better solution. I'm using media queries to hide just the language drop down text, thus retaining the icon (and with it the options).

Comment: Your updated solution is simple and elegant! I like it! I marked this as a solution to my problem. Thanks!